# Fetching only JSON Object from response

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, react-native, fetch

I am building a REST API using NodeJS, MySQL for React Native front end application. The mysql database returns a JSON object when I give URL to fetch. When I get the JSON, it consist of lot more information rather than just JSON Object containing data from mysql database. I have attached screenshot of response data.[image: JSON response data]

I want to extract only data containing array of object i.e [{id:, name:, address}] to my state variable in react native. So that I can map that array to View for displaying data.

Below is code of getButton(), if I click on this button it fetches the data from server and sets state variable.

```
getButton = () => {
        fetch("http://localhost:8082/customers", { method: "GET" })
            .then((responseData) => {
                console.log(responseData);
                this.setState({ apiData: responseData })
            })
            .done();
    }
```

Please help me out and let me know if further details on code is needed.

Comment: That's not the JSON, that's the [`Response` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) which a `fetch` resolves to.

Comment: Please share your API details. Especially line which is returning response.

Comment: `app.get('/customers', function (req, res) {
       con.query("select * from customers", function(error, rows, fields) {
            if(!!error) console.log('error');
            else{
                console.log(rows)
               res.send(rows);
            }
        });
    })`

This is my api

Comment: @bergi Please let me know the original question's link that resembles my question. Thanks

Comment: @Sameer It's right there in the box at the top of the post.

Comment: ahh my bad. Pardon me

Comment: I found it Bergi, I appreciate your help.